# WP move style css with wp_head function

Tags: css, wordpress, performance, seo, styles

I have this css code inside the `Body` tag on my Wordpress webpage:

```
<style type="text/css" id="et-builder-advanced-style"> 
    //some css here 
</style>
```

I need to put it inside `Head` tag for performance and SEO purposes. I searched for it and found inside `includes\builder\functions.php` this code:

```
function et_pb_maybe_add_advanced_styles() {
      $styles['et-builder-advanced-style'] = ET_Builder_Element::get_style();
      $styles['et-builder-page-custom-style'] = et_pb_get_page_custom_css();

      foreach( $styles as $id => $style_data ) {
        if ( ! $style_data ) {
            continue;
        }

        printf(
            '<style type="text/css" id="%2$s">
                %1$s
            </style>',
            $style_data,
            esc_attr( $id )
        );
      }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'et_pb_maybe_add_advanced_styles', 1 );
```

So i tried to change the last part so it looks like `add_action( 'wp_head', ...` but is not working.

As I said I need it for performance purposes, I want the page to load all this css styles before painting the whole page, so moving it with JS is not an alternative.

PD: Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

`wp_head()` function will work for you, first of all check in your current theme's files (most likely `header.php`) to make sure that the `wp_head()` function is being called.

Your code must run before the `wp_head` hook fires or nothing will happen.

I guess you are trying to hook that function too late. Maybe from a theme template file after `get_header` function. You can place that code in the theme's `functions.php` file and it should work.

Comment: `wp_head()` is being called. I placed the function inside theme's `function.php` and isnt working. The style isnt appending on the `Head` tag

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, i am really not sure about that. you can ask question on meta i guess.